# Confusing 'readline' warning in the documentation

Tags: python, pyserial

I am trying to implement serial communication, following [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18569224/serial-communication-over-usb-converter-in-python-how-to-aproach-this).

Basically I will have a separate thread, that blocks, listening to the port, and when a complete line is received, push it to a global queue.

However, this warning in the documentation is confusing to me:

> [readlines() only works with a timeout](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/shortintro.html#readline)

What does it mean? How do I implement what I intend. I would **hate** to have to

```
while True:
    a = self.ser.read(1)
    if a == '/n':
        blqblq()
    elif a == '/r'
        b = self.ser.read(1)
        if b == '/n':
            nana()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

readline**s** must be given a timeout because otherwise it would never finish, since there is no way to detect the end of the serial data stream (EOF).

`readline` blocks indefinitely when no data is being sent (or the data doesn't contain a newline), but so does your application. It's perfectly fine to write something like

```
def read(ser, queue):
    while True:
         queue.put(ser.readline())
threading.Thread(target=read, args=(ser, queue)).start()
```

or the more modern equivalent

```
def read(ser, queue):
    for line in ser:
         queue.put(line)
threading.Thread(target=read, args=(ser, queue)).start()
```

However, you should be aware that the reading thread will never finish. So *if* your program should ever end in a non-exceptional way (i.e. the user can somehow quit it), you need to have a mechanism to signal the reading thread to stop. To make sure that this signal is ever received, you need to use a timeout - otherwise, the thread could block indefinitely in the absence of serial data. For example, this could look like:

```
def read(ser, queue):
    buf = b''
    ser.timeout = 1  # 1 second. Modify according to latency requirements
    while not should_stop.is_set():
         buf += ser.readline()
         if buf.endswith('\n'):
             queue.put(line)
             buf = b''
         # else: Interrupted by timeout

should_stop = threading.Event()
threading.Thread(target=read, args=(ser, queue)).start()
# ... somewhat later
should_stop.set()  # Reading thread will exit within the next second
```

Comment: Thank you for the code example. But what should be added to enable host-side (not device side, but the PC the program is running on) closing of the program. I am new to threading and really don't know where to start.

Comment: Ammended the answer - you'll want to use an [Event](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/threading.html#threading.Event).